# TLS certificate failure, php to gmail

Tags: php, openssl, gmail, swiftmailer, cradle

```
bin/cradle auth-verify-mail auth_id=1 auth_slug=taku.haider1987@gmail.com auth_updated=123456 host=localhost
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\Heroes\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 95
```

https://cradlephp.github.io/

I'm using cradle for php -> openssl -> swiftmailer for connecting to gmail.

I get the above auth error while sending smtp.gmail.com:587

Openssl should be able to handle tls. I double checked username/password, ports are forwarded through router, firewall has exceptions, different ports, bypass dns and attempted passing cacert.pem

I would greatly appreciate advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're getting here is that when you connect over TLS, your TLS client does not have a copy of the public root certificate that Gmail's certificate is signed with, so it can't verify it.

It's most likely that your CA certificate bundle is out of date. Gmail changed the CA it uses a couple of years ago to one that was not supported in many older OSs. This was generally fixed in package updates (so do `apt full-upgrade` or whatever equivalent your server OS uses), but sometimes it wasn't.

An alternative explanation is that you're asking your client to connect to gmail, but the connection is being intercepted and redirected to your hosting provider's mail server (this is fairly common), which obviously doesn't provide a certificate that matches `smtp.gmail.com`, so verification fails.

I can't tell which of these is the problem without seeing more debug output from the rest of the SMTP conversation.

While I know that you're using SwiftMailer, the PHPMailer docs have [an extensive description of this problem and how to solve it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure), and the same measures will work for SwiftMailer too.